# Is it advisable to play Legacy without having played Pandemic before?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-legacy-season-1

My group and I are planning to start playing Pandemic Legacy.

While we haven't played Pandemic before, we're accustomed to decision making games like Dead of Winter or Small World.
As I understand it, a *normal* round of Pandemic is hard enough to win for beginners, so the question came up if starting with Pandemic Legacy would be an enjoyable experience for us at all.

Without to many spoilers:
Would we possibly be able to grasp the concepts of Pandemic while playing the Legacy version, even enough to win a percentage of the games?

Comment: If you've played other games, I wouldn't use the word "hard" but maybe I've been lucky.  The game is challenging but I've played far harder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go for it and have fun!

The [Pandemic Legacy rulebook](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-pandemic-legacy-rules_lr.pdf) covers this contingency on page 3, telling you what sections of the rules to use to play a "vanilla" Pandemic game and advises you to play that way at least twice before starting the Legacy campaign.

Comment: So we don't need the base version of the game, but should play a couple of rounds before entering full Legacy mode.

Comment: @npst - Exactly, either way its a great game

Comment: If you don't mind losing your first couple of games, the game is self-balancing, so it would be fine to jump straight in.  But I'd agree that playing the game vanilla a couple of times is a good idea.

Comment: And honestly by half way through playing the Legacy version you are playing a different game and that is all I am willing to say without getting into spoilers